# How can i change this localStorage function to react native AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native

```
const Storage = (cartItems) => {
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cartItems.length > 0 ? cartItems: []));
}

export const sumItems = cartItems => {
    Storage(cartItems);
    let itemCount = cartItems.reduce((total, product) => total + product.quantity, 0);
    let total = cartItems.reduce((total, product) => total + product.price * product.quantity, 0).toFixed(2);
    return { itemCount, total }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked AsyncStorage documentation already? It is very straightforward and easy to implement. https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage

Answer (score 0):

Please install this =>
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/async-storage

then u can set u data in key
for eg=>

1. hello is your data
2. u are saving your data on [ yes key ]

await AsyncStorage.setItem('Yes','Hello'}));

Answer (score 0):

1. install this library

```
npm i @react-native-community/async-storage
```

2. you have to set a key and on that key, u have to save your data like this
   in this eg => we store `true` in `hello`

```js
await AsyncStorage.setItem('hello', 'true');
```

3. if you want the `hello` value

```js
let a = AsyncStorage.getItem('hello')
console.log(a);
```

4. result

```sh
true
```